# Close browser tab and exit Angular2 application

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I am working on an Angular2 application. In this application, I want to provide a button to the user which when clicked will close the application and the browser tab in which it was opened.

I tried searching for the solution but didn't find anything much on it. One approach suggested was to call onDestroy for all the components to prevent any memory leak. However I don't have much concrete to go forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot as of now it is only possible in IE AFAIK and with chrome or firefox you will encounter error like this

> app.component.ts:43 Scripts may close only the windows that were
>   opened by it

You can look at this answer for more info https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133744/why-do-browsers-disallow-script-closing-an-opener-window-yet-allow-changing-its